# Distribution of linear combination of discrete variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

Assume $X,Y$ are discrete independent random variables with known distribution $P_X(x), P_Y(y)$ and $c_1, c_2$ constants.

Can we determine the shape of the distribution of:

$Z = c_1~X+c_2~Y$

Comment: Can you? Yes! Does it lead to simple formulae ... Norma always.

Comment: I forgot to mention that they are also independent. Does it lead to a simple formula now?

Comment: Discrete convolution will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are independent, $P_{XY}(X=x,Y=y)=P_X(X=x)P_Y(Y=y)$

To get the distribution of $Z$, we form the discrete convolution:

$$P(Z=z)=\sum_{x \in \mathbb{R}} P_{XY}\left(x,\frac{z-c_1x}{c_2}\right)$$